# What could make text on dojo input/select on top of everything?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I have a css rendered menu (`ul` `li`...etc), what beneath is a stack of dijit component rendered by dojo. The problem is showing in the image below, which only happens on IE7, but works fine on IE8/9, firefox and chrome.

The layout of the dijit components(border, style) are all under the menu, but only user entered text is on TOP OF EVERYTHING.

I heard about `window` object is always on top of every `windowless` components, that would may sense that the  is on top of `ui`..`li` menu, however, for testing purpose I create a plain  object and its text is under the menu! I am very confused now.

Here are the codes for dijitTextInput and plain text input:

Dijit text input:

```
<div id="widget__personName_id" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInlineTable dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitValidationTextBox" role="presentation" widgetid="_personName_id">
    <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer">
        <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" type="text" role="presentation" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="Χ">
    </div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
        <input id="_personName_id" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" name="personName" autocomplete="off" dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode" maxlength="255" tabindex="0" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the plain input

```
<input name="personName" size="50">
```

So could anyone give a hint, about where can I start to find a clue to make text on dijit input box under the menu?

[image]

Comment: Look at the page in chrome. Press F12. Right click on the problem area. Click "Inspect Element" It will show you the page structure and all CSS styles on the object, it should be helpful.

Comment: @TheWaxMann Thanks, I get fireBug on FF, it just very very messy as dojo get tons of css and javascript dealing very small task..but I will try again, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hint as requested:
This is the matter of z-index in css codes.

Higher the z-index means that it is above those who have lower z-index value.
Z-index must exist with 'position' value (position absolute or relative)